# Number of lines in code

Tags: c#

Is there a tool or something else to count the number of lines in a specific C# project? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: Curiosity is fine, but I just want to point out that SLOC is normally a terrible "metric."  Eww.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code#Disadvantages

Comment: @Andy: Unless you bill by them... I think IBM used to do that.

Comment: Nah, it´s just plain curiosity.

Comment: The more lines of code the better the system, Windows is 16 million

Comment: @Chris S, Windows is far more than 16 million lines of code [link](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Source_lines_of_code#Example)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe there are tools, but I find it easier to just use the Find in Files option and use this regex:

```
^~(:Wh@//.+)~(:Wh@\{:Wh@)~(:Wh@\}:Wh@)~(:Wh@/#).+
```

That regex is from [here](http://blog.schuager.com/2009/01/line-count-in-visual-studio.html), which also shows how to search for it. It will return a number of matching lines (i.e. the number of lines in your code)

Comment: Wow! What a hack!

Comment: it returns LOC correctly but it excludes "{", "}" expressions, how can we add "{", "}" to count?

Comment: `^~(:Wh@//.+)~(:Wh@/#).+` should do it.

Comment: This answer is wrong with VS 2013, where VS has updated the regex to use standard regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008010/why-does-visual-studio-use-such-a-strange-regex-syntax#answer-22065370

Comment: Doesn't work in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @Sangram same issue here.

Comment: As said, regex in this answer doesn't work from VS2012. Instead use in Find in Files this simple regular expression: ^. (tick Use Regular Expressions and in file types enter *.cs) to list all the lines including white spaces. At the end of the Find Results window you will have 'Matching lines' . Or another approximation, removing lines with just white spaces or parenthesis:  ^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\w

Answer (score 16):

In Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Ultimate, you can go to the Analyze tab and select "Calculate Code Metrics", it gives you lines of code as well as a maintainability index, cyclomatic complexity, depth of inheritance and class coupling metrics, project by project.

You can drill into namespaces and classes/interfaces as well.

Comment: You're right, thanks -- I mistyped "Pro" for "Premium" -- I've updated the answer above.

Comment: To anyone looking to use this, make sure your solution compiles before you run code metrics. I just did this on a rather large solution only to get an error 15 minutes later about my lack of a semicolon in one file.

Comment: This feature is available in 2012 "Pro"

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio does that if you use its "Code Analysis" tool.

Edit: a 10-second google search (with the terms *sloc count c#*) returns this Code Project article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorylinecounter.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success with [David Wheeler's SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/). It's a command line tool, which will require Cygwin unfortunately, but I found it handled very large Java projects without fuss. C# is listed as a supported language for counting. Configuration is minimal, IIRC I just pointed it at a directory and it summarised all the type of code and broke it down in lines per language.

Highly recommended.

Comment: +1 -- I've used this tool numerous times. It accounts for comments and the like and works flawlessly.