# Why does Visual Studio use such a strange regex syntax

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, syntax

Is there any reason why Visual Studio uses such a strange syntax (for instance in the search/replace dialog)?

Instead of writing `\s*(\w+) = new Process\(\)` I have to write `:b*{:a+} = new Process\(\)`.
I am always struggling with this syntax - especially since the normal [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) syntax is the former one.

This is an incomplete comparison between the two syntaxes:

```
What            Visual  .NET   Comment
                Studio
----------------------------------------------------------------
Tab/Spaces      :b       \s    Either tab or space
Alphanumeric    :a       \w    ([a-zA-Z0-9])
Subexpression   {}       ()
Substitution    \n       $n    Substitutes the substring matched 
                               by a numbered subexpression.
Backreference   \n       \n    Matches the value of a numbered 
                               subexpression.
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

See here ([Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx), [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)) for more information.

Is there any reason for this? Is it historical? Is there any advantage?

Comment: Link to conversion table from strange to normal syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I quote Coding Horror:

> However, you're in for an unpleasant
>   surprise when you attempt to actually
>   use regular expressions to find
>   anything in Visual Studio. Apparently
>   the Visual Studio IDE has its own
>   bastardized regular expression syntax.
>   Why? Who knows. Probably for arcane
>   backwards compatibility reasons,
>   although I have no idea why you'd want
>   to perpetually carry forward insanity.
>   Evidently it makes people
>   billionaires, so who am I to judge.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html

Comment: thanks for the link - the first screenshot in the article is great - it shows what happens when I push the arrow button I always overlooked and ignored ^^

Answer (score 18):

The good news:

[Since Visual Studio 2013, the search uses standard .NET regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx):

> Visual Studio uses .NET Framework regular expressions to find and replace text. For more information about .NET regular expressions, see .NET Framework Regular Expressions.
>   Before Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio used custom regular expression syntax in the Find and Replace windows. See Visual Studio Regular Expression Conversions for an explanation of how to convert some of the more commonly-used custom regular expression symbols to the .NET versions.

No need anymore to learn a strange regular expression flavour.

Comment: a link that requires login makes me sad =(

Comment: The standard .NET regular expressions still use non-standard syntax

Answer (score 6):

Well, they tried to make it "easier" to use, it seems, for a C++ coder.

Consider they provided new non-standard expressions, like

```
C/C++ Identifier
:i
Matches the expression ([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*)

Quoted string
:q
Matches the expression (("[^"]*")|('[^']*')).
```

I think the reason it has completely different syntax is so the regex user clearly sees its non-standard and **not the same** as normal regex.

Which is good. All in all its a good regex engine and easy to use.

Comment: I am not sure if that's a good thing. At least I am struggling a lot with this special syntax. But I have to admit, that I am programming a lot without Visual Studio. Maybe it is easier when you use it every day. But either way - no matter which regex engine I use they seem to be quite similar, with the exception of Visual Studio where everything is different :/

Comment: I want to search for an occurrence of 2 to 5 particular letters followed by 1 to 2 numbers. In "real" reg ex I'd maybe do this:
<[a-z]{2,5}[0-9]{1,2}>
but in visual studio... I can't do it. Micro$oft should at least allow the use of POSIX reg ex.

Answer (score 1):

My best and most honest answer is because they are Microsoft therefore they can use whatever standard they choose.  Some programmer somewhere probably decided that the above syntax was clearer to them or easier to code for and therefore it became canon law.