# How do I match data in XML using Visual Studio's 2010 crazy regular expression syntax?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

Regular expressions in visual studio [are frustrating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3008010/607407). This is probably because it's Microsoft's standard to ignore any standards and make it's own.

I' trying to match the following ([regex1010 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VsACoQ/1)):

```
 <bind_pattern name='([A-Z\-_]+)' value='view_line_(in|out)puts' *\/>
```

I figured out that I need to replace braces `()` with curly braces `{}`:

```
<bind_pattern name='{[A-Z\-_]+}' value='view_line_{in|out}puts' *\/>
```

It still doesn't match, what else should I change?

Comment: Upgrade your VS and enjoy "normal" regexps in Find and Replace. Note you need to escape `<` and `>`

Comment: Try `\<bind_pattern name='{[A-Z_-]+}' value='view_line_{in|out}puts' */\>`.

Comment: That says "Syntax error in pattern". It does not provide any details what's wrong. Just popup with this error. I'll probably open the file in another editor.

Comment: Maybe that is because  I removed the escape from `-`? Also, the `<` and `>` are `\b` in "normal" regex, maybe here, you need to use `[<]` and `[>]`

Comment: Also, it seems that `()` should work. Try `[<]bind_pattern name='([A-Z\-_]+)' value='view_line_(in|out)puts' */[>]`