# Calculate lines of code using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a program that loads all .cs files in a project and calculates their lines of code.

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068703/number-of-lines-in-code) topic, you can use the following regular expression: `^~(:Wh@//.+)~(:Wh@{:Wh@)~(:Wh@}:Wh@)~(:Wh@/#).+`. The problem here, however, is that it does not work. I am not getting any matches, `neither programmatically` or through the `Search and replace function` in Visual Studio (2012).

Another [webpage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/625710/Line-Counting-Trickery-within-Visual-Studio) found online provides the following regex: `^(?([^\r\n])\s)[^\s+?/]+[^\n]$`. This does not return the expected lines of code either. Where I am getting 27001 through code-metrics, the regular expression returns well over 50000.

The code used is as follows. I use two methods, one to get all the .cs-files in the project, and the other to actually calculate the lines for each .cs-file.

```
private static List < string > GetAllCSFiles(FileInfo projectFile) {
XDocument projectDoc = XDocument.Load(projectFile.FullName);
if (projectDoc.Root == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("projectFile");

XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
List < XElement > nodes = projectDoc.Descendants(ns + "Compile")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("Include") != null).ToList();

List < string > csList = nodes.Select(element => element.Attribute("Include").Value).Where(x => x.Contains(".cs")).ToList();
return csList;
}

public static int CalculateLinesOfCode(FileInfo projectFile) {
int lineCount = 0;
string projectLocation = projectFile.DirectoryName;
if (projectLocation == null)
    return -1;

List < string > csList = GetAllCSFiles(projectFile);
const string Pattern = @"^:b*[^:b#/]+.*$";

foreach(string csFile in csList) {
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(projectLocation, csFile);
    FileInfo csFileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);
    if (!csFileInfo.Exists)
        continue;

    string[] uncheckedLines = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath);
    foreach(string uncheckedLine in uncheckedLines) {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(uncheckedLine, Pattern))
            lineCount++;
    }
}

return lineCount;
}
```

The pattern shown above is the latest from the second provided link.

All projects get loaded and read into the stringarray as expected, I debugged through it and found all lines my program had. The regex however does not work as expected.

**Two questions where one rules out the other if answered**

1. What is a correctly working regex to calculate lines of code?
2. Is there an alternative (better?) way to calculate lines of code programmatically?

Comment: You also should think about maintenance. You can't write your own regex, but you want to use it, because "it's more compact". What will be when you want to edit your regex or improve it? You'll go to Stackoverflow and ask a question. That's what will be. What if you want to debug regex, because sometimes it's work as expected and sometimes don't? Nothing. You just can't do it.

Comment: Actually, asking for help regards creating a regex sufficient for my problem is also a good learning opportunity. I can break down the regex and see what each aspect of the expression is responsible for. But I can understand where you're coming from. Although such a demeaning comment probably isn't worth responding to..

Comment: Of course it's a good learning opportunity. But if you're writing software in a team, it's also became a good learning opportunity for all team members. I'm just trying to say that you shouldn't use regex if you can. If you are just learning them, sorry for my inappropriate comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would check if the file new line characters are `\r\n` (windows like system) or just `\n` (unix like system). Once I figure that out, I would then split the lines based on the new line character(s). When you get all the lines, simply loop through them and check if the line is not empty. If it's not empty, you have a code line.

**EDIT:**

Sample code

```
    public static void GetNumberOfCodeLines(string text, out int linesOfCode, out int totalLines)
    {
        linesOfCode = 0;
        totalLines = 0;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            // there is no code in this text
            return;
        }

        string[] lines = null;

        // test for windows like system new line
        if (text.IndexOf("\r\n") > -1)
        {
            lines = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        } // test for unix like systems new line
        else if (text.IndexOf('\n') > -1)
        {
            lines = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        }
        else
        {
            // it's just 1 line of code
            linesOfCode = 1;
            totalLines = 1;
            return;
        }

        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            totalLines++;

            string lineTest = line.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\t' });

            if (lineTest.Length > 0 && !lineTest.StartsWith("//") && lineTest != "{" && lineTest != "}" )
            {
                linesOfCode++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about comments and lines that only contain { and }? They should not be included into the calculation.

Comment: @Matthijs: I wrote you short sample which includes check for { } and // lines

Comment: While I do appreciate the effort, this is not really what I am looking for. A regex checking if the line matches is something more compact. I do not want such a method and have each line of code run through these various checks. As you can see in my already provided code, a stringarray containing of all the lines inside a .cs-file is provided. This has to be checked, rather than a single line.

Comment: @Matthijs: No worries, but, I'm sure that this approach will give you better performance than Regex.

Comment: What you are doing here is splitting up one line into several lines, actually allowing a returning value higher than 1 for `each` line. This is not wanted behavior. One line is either matching to be a code-line or is not matching.

Comment: @Matthijs: Actually, you are wrong, the method expects text read from the file (File.ReadAllText) and not just one line.

Comment: That would explain a lot, because I am reading text through ReadAllLines, rather than ReadAllText. What is the purpose of using ReadAllText as opposed to ReadAllLines?

Comment: @Matthijs: ReadAllText reads all the text from the file and it does not split the lines. ReadAllLines reads the text and splits the lines to string array.

Comment: But you are splitting the lines into an array yourself in this method. Why manually do it when there is an easy and already existing method for it? Sounds a bit like re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I have tried your method and see the results. 37896 lines of code as opposed to the code metrics result of 27001. Getting closer but still not there.

Comment: As I said, this method expects the 'string' as input, you can simply change it to accept the string array and then use ReadAllLines. I'm not reinventing a wheel, I would sure not use ReadAllLines for a large file like 2GB (which will never happen for code files) but read block by block...

Comment: @Matthijs: I did not run this method so I don't know if it works correctly.. it's just a sample to show you how this can be done.